# ag-grid: Show rightmost column on load

Tags: ag-grid

How to load a grid with the initial view scrolled to the right most column?

Docs for Column Properties say:

lockPosition    Set to true to always have column displayed first.

But setting lockPosition: true on the right most column does not change the initial display.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lockPosition: true moves the column to the left most.

To scroll to any column on initial grid load:

in onGridReady function:
params.api.ensureColumnVisible("column field id");